# How do I install protobuf 2.5 on Arch Linux for compiling hadoop 2.6.0 using maven 3.3.1?

Tags: linux, hadoop, maven-3

Am looking for installing protobuf 2.5.0 on Arch Linux, so that protoc-2.5.0.so is installed on the OS, so that I can go ahead with building hadoop 2.6.0 from source and make my life easy! :)

BTW, protobuf 2.6.0 does not compile when hadoop is built from source I have tried that as well. Ubuntu 14.04 comes with protoc 2.5.0. I DO NOT want to use Ubuntu.

Please check the screenshot first (there is no protobuf 2.5.0), since the problem lies there.. I guess
am getting the following exception, I am aware that protoc is not installed in arch linux currently.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:2.6.0:protoc (compile-protoc)
>   on project hadoop-common:
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: 'protoc --version' did
>   not return a version -> [Help 1]

Please help me out, since, I have spent 4 hours every day from two days, with no luck.

Answer (score 37):

Compiling Google's protobuf is pretty easy.
I originally found out how to do it on [this blog post](http://www.csrdu.org/nauman/2014/01/23/geting-started-with-hadoop-2-2-0-building/) while compiling hadoop myself.

But here is my version:

```
$ cd /usr/local/src/
$ wget https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v2.5.0/protobuf-2.5.0.tar.gz
$ tar xvf protobuf-2.5.0.tar.gz
$ cd protobuf-2.5.0
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr
$ make
$ make install
$ protoc --version
```

Install protobuf for java

```
$ cd java
$ mvn install
$ mvn package
```

You should be good to go.

To enable you to install different versions of protobuf, install `stow`
then change `./configure --prefix=/usr` to `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/stow/protobuf-2.5.0`

Then link protobuf into your system with stow:

```
$ cd /usr/local/stow
$ stow protobuf-2.5.0
```

Note: `stow` uses /usr/local/bin by default. Make sure thats in your `$PATH`

To unlink that version of protobuf,

```
$ stow -D protobuf-2.5.0
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just by following until "You should be good to go" WORKED like a CHAMP. You were really helpful.

Did not encounter any issues while compiling.



[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:11 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-04-22T19:46:26+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 167M/1624M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Upvoting this one since it also useful for other distros (f.e. Debian went from protobuf 2.4 to 2.6 so couldn't find any debs for 2.5).

Answer (score 2):

I wonder why the above answer got downvoted,even I had to perform few more steps (in addition to the accepted answer by Rudker) to get protobuf 2.5 installed on Ubuntu Xenial.

Leaving the additional steps here for everyone's benefit:

`apt-get install autoconf` in response to the error : `./autogen.sh: autoreconf: not found` for command : `./autogen.sh`

`apt-get install libtool` in response to the error : `autoreconf: libtoolize is needed because this package uses Libtool` for command : `./autogen.sh`

`apt install g++` in response to the error : `configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check` for command : `./configure --prefix=/usr`

Answer (score 0):

An easier but not future proof solution (for future queries) would be to head over to Arch Linux Archives: http://seblu.net/a/archive/packages/p/protobuf/

Uninstall the newer version of protobuf and install the downloaded package via pacman -U protobuf-2.5.x..

Though whenever you upgrade the Arch Linux packages via pacman you'd need to ensure you are doing: sudo pacman -Syu --ignore protobuf

Comment: Above link broken (the site got reorganized) no obvious replacement link.

Answer (score 0):

I currently don't have enough *reputation* to comment, so I add a answer here to update the top voted answer.

Since *protobuf* move to different repo, the new *wget* command should be:

```
wget https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v2.5.0/protobuf-2.5.0.tar.gz
```

And in order to run *./autogen.sh*, you may need install these:

```
sudo yum install libtool automake autoconf
```

For OSX prerequisites, try *SunitaKoppar*'s answer (I don't know why the down-votes).

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for the steps. Just wanted to add that, to get autogen.sh to work, I had to install the below packages (commands for mac below):

> brew install gtk
>
> brew install autoconf
>
> brew install automake